# How to remove Save Button from form view

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I used openerp version 7 & i created a form view.but its only used to display data .not to add / edit data.above 2 selection boxes for query records.

my requirement is need to remove **save** button from top left corner

[image: screen]

**EDITED** : 
Code added for relevant to that area

```
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="bpl_worker_summary_action">
        <field name="name">Worker Summary</field>
        <field name="res_model">bpl.worker.summary</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    </record>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="bpl_worker_summary_form">
<field name="name">Worker Summary</field>
<field name="model">bpl.worker.summary</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<form string='bpl_worker_summary' create="false" edit="false"  version='7.0' >
<sheet>
<group>
<group>
    <field name='bpl_company_id' readonly="1" />
    <field name='bpl_estate_id' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the save button, you can modify the access right for the logged in user that shouldn't be able to save.

The access rights rule will be such that the user or preferrably his group wouldn't have "`write`" access to the "`object`"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `create="false"` attribute in `form` tag. It will disable **Create** button from form view. You can use `edit="false"` to disable **Edit** button.

If you want to disable button from form view then use this:

```
<form create="false" edit="false">
```

If you want to disable button from tree view then use this:

```
<tree create="false">
```

Comment: its ok with my tree view 
but not work with form tag
<form string='worker info' create="false" version='7.0' >

Comment: `create` option will remove Create button & `edit` option will remove Edit option. I think there is no option to remove save button.

Comment: yes.I need to remove that Save button.because this form only for view purpose

Comment: You need to add create="false" in both form and tree views. If you will only apply it for form view, then if you will open any existing record from tree view to form, you will not see create button on form view but you will be able to see create from tree view and you can create from there. So, apply it for both of views and update your module. It will work. By doing this, one cant create a new record that's it. I cant suggest you to remove save button as its by default architecture and if you will change architecture code, it will remove from all views.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was talking. Agree with @PriyeshSolanki

Answer (score -3):

Disable the `Edit` and `Create` buttons. The `Save` button appears when you click `Edit` or `Create` Button. I hope this helps.